# Batch Creating a septate batch file and executing it internally

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

I have made this code and it makes a septate batch file and then executes it but it closes when I execute it does any one know what I have done wrong. This is the un-install code for the software.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
(
 echo @echo off
 echo echo Start
 echo pause
 echo del /s /f /q "Path1"
 echo del /s /f /q "Path2"
 echo del /s /f /q "Path3"
 echo cls
 echo echo Done
 echo pause
 echo (del /q /f "%~dpfnx0" ^& exit /6 0)
) > "%~dp0uni.bat"
uni.bat
```

Comment: You need to escape the `)` in the last echo line.  The opening bracket isn't an issue in batch files but the closing one is actually closing the loop prematurely as it isn't escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

```
call uni.bat
```

otherwise execution is transferred to the target batchfile and no return is invoked.

Comment: I have worked out that it is  echo (del /q /f "%~dpfnx0" & exit /6 0) that is the problem

Comment: Yes - yu'd need to escape that `&` by prefixing it with a caret (`^`) - so try echoing `...^&...`